# CSS Menu hovering not working on Android device

Tags: css, menu

I know touch devices like Android tablets/phones do not support CSS hover events, because you cannot hover on a touch device. So a CSS menu is not advisible for touch devices.

Although I noticed that some websites have fixed this by making the first click/tap the hover event and second click/tap open the link in the menu item.

I tried to find out how that is done, but I cannot get it to work on [www.hetweeractueel.nl](http://www.hetweeractueel.nl). Has anyone tips how to get this behaviour work on www.hetweeractueel.nl?

Comment: It works fine on iOS and my Android device.

Comment: Strange, not on my Samsung S3. Also visitors complain that it is not working on a samsung Galaxy Tab2. If I tap the menu link 'Nederland actueel' it does two things: it collapses the menu, but also opens the link. While I expect that one click only collapses the menu.

Answer (score -1):

I've read that holding the link then swiping away will leave you with the hover behavior (http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/472609-android-browsers-mouse-over.html#post3723631).

I've seen it work in one case on an emulator, but haven't tested beyond that.